# zkoss changes in model or change page, force grid with paging to reload

Tags: grid, paging, reload, zk

I am using zkoss, so in zul i am using a grid component with paging mold.

I don't want to reload grid every model operation.

When I remove paging mold the results is OK.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't get it. Please tell us what behavior you expect. And a small code example would be nice to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you have associated model associated with your grid. When you perform any operation. You are notifying that model object associated too, so it is being called again. All you have to do is to check for any notification code refereeing to that model upon your operation. Once you have removed that notification from there, getSampleModel() associated with grid won't be called.

If you share you code where you are performing operation, i can remove that notification for you too.